# Trigger with query data

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have table with the informations:

```
INSERT INTO Transferencias
('Origem_Apostador_ID', 'Destino_Apostador_ID', 'Valor_Transferido')
VALUES
('1', '6', '200.00');
```

And I need to get value '200.00' and sum with the data from another table after this value have been insert on table to this table below:

```
INSERT INTO Conta
('Apostador_ID', 'Saldo', 'Qtd_Saque', 'Qtd_Deposito', 'Qtd_Transferencia')
VALUES
('1', '700.00', '0', '1', '0');
```

I have no idea how can I use data from query to do the update on "Saldo" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t know if I understood your question correctly, but i think you need something like this:

```
UPDATE Conta 
   SET Saldo = Saldo + (SELECT Valor_Transferido FROM Transferencias WHERE Origem_Apostador_ID = '1') 
 WHERE Apostador_ID = '1';
```

You can add this code to some trigger if you want to. You can find many examples out there for simple triggers to do the work depending on your database.

**TRIGGER EXAMPLE ON MYSQL**

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_UPDATE_SALDO BEFORE INSERT ON Transferencias
FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       IF NEW.Valor_Transferido > 0 THEN

    --Increments the destination account
    UPDATE Conta 
       SET Saldo = Saldo + NEW.Valor_Transferido 
     WHERE Apostador_ID = NEW.Destino_Apostador_ID;

    --Subtracts the origin account
    UPDATE Conta 
       SET Saldo = Saldo - NEW.Valor_Transferido 
     WHERE Apostador_ID = NEW.Origem_Apostador_ID;
       END IF;
   END;
```

Comment: Almost there, "WHERE Apostador_ID = '1';" I don't know what is the Apostador_ID, I need to get this value dynamic that is why I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can create an INSERT TRIGGER on the "Transferencias" table that will update the "Conta" table on the "Saldo" column. When you are in the context of a trigger, you know the record ID and all other information that you might use. Here is an link to some documentation on triggers (mysql): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

You could change the "Apostador_ID = '1'" to something like "Apostador_ID = NEW.Origem_Apostador_ID" inside the context of your Transferencias trigger.